# Multiply to Combine XYZ vs Combine XYZ to Multiply

Tags: node-editor, shaders, transforms, mathematics, vector

I was translating the object's origin by Vector Math node. Though I'm a bit confused of why feeding Multiply & Combine XYZ on a different order yields different results. I thought both vectors will result in the same (X,Y) position, or is there something that I'm missing? If anyone could shine some light on this that'd be much appreciated! Thank you.

Combine XYZ to Multiply:
[image: Combine XYZ to Multiply]

Multiply to Combine XYZ:
[image: Multiply to Combine XYZ]

Comment: Replace the Math node with a "Vector Math" node set to multiply. The colors of the dot in the input/output of your nodes must be the same (purple is a Vector value, grey is a float value, yellow is a color value (RGB)), else conversions will be automatically done by the engine, and results may vary